# Question should be updated after certain amount of time?

Tags: support, answers

So I was searching for a solution to my problem on SO and then I realized that most of the questions have answered in '08 or '10 etc. Its 2014 now and there are better implementations with better documentation exists than the most voted answer or the accepted answer.

The problem is that the people who know the current state of technology aren't going to search questions to which they already know the answer and people like me do not know the answer. So questions and solutions remains outdated.

Is there some mechanism which already exists to tackle this and if not then shouldn't there be one?

Comment: I don't think this is as big an issue as you believe. Most these situations are solved by new questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always add an up-to-date answer to old questions yourself. If you don't know a better answer, or don't want to write one, then you can always bring attention to the question by:

1. Bringing it up in [an appropriate chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/).
2. Placing a bounty on it:

   [image: Screenshot]
3. Bring it up on Meta?

I'm not really sure if that last one is actually an appropriate use of Meta. The first two, however, will definitely help bring attention to questions that need new up-to-date answers.

Comment: I am talking about people like me.. who dont have enough reputation to do that.. They cannot anyhow make that question 'active' and if we try to post another question then it gets marked duplicate by esteemed members.

Comment: @Vedanshu you have 25 rep, which is enough to go to a chat room and point out that the answers to a question are outdated.

Comment: umm... yeah I can do that but I don't agree that this is a solution rather than a fix.. Besides people even newer than me couldn't even bring it on the chat room

Comment: I agree with Vedanshu - the issue is if it is outdated if nobody starts a bounty on it, the quality of the answer is bad and it is still occupying the top space in the google search. People might even not notice this simple fact. This actually reduces the quality of stack overflow question/answers and I think it should be at least open to discussion here as a feature request. For instance submitting that current answers outdated without a bounty, and the person asking the question or someone else with sufficient reputation can verify/approve that.